# List files all files in folder on Sharepoint online with C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Trying to list all files in a directory in Sharepoint online. But get an exception on line *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'List 'Shared%20Documents' does not exist at site with URL 'https://MySite.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamSite'.'*

The directory exists and finds it and under the directory when retrieving the directory.  Do not know if it is the right way to retrieve a file from Sharepoint online.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using OfficeDevPnP.Core;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Sharepoint
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string siteUrl = "https://MySite.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamSite";
        List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();

        using (var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, appId, AppSecred))
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;

            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.Load(web.Lists);
            clientContext.Load(web, wb => wb.ServerRelativeUrl);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Shared%20Documents/Testfolder/");
            clientContext.Load(folder);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared%20Documents");
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //Throws an exception. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'List 'Shared%20Documents' does not exist at site with URL 'https://MySite.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamSite'.'

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'><Query></Query></View>";
            camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
           
            // Todo
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using the literal name `Shared Documents`, instead of the escaped one? Also be aware, that the url will be the initial name of that list, but if you can change the title of that list

Comment: Yes, but same result. Unfortunately, there must be a space in the directory name. Works on the step before so do not think that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Documents` instead of `Shared Documents` or you can always use `context.web.Lists.GetbyID(system.GUID('yourlistguid'))` to get list by it's id

Comment: where I can fine the id?

Comment: That's basically the GUID that you can find by going to list settings and checking 'List' query string parameter in the Url.